# Active/Deactive Game object don't work for me in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to use `setactive(true)` for a Game object after  use `setactive(false)` but don't work for me .

please help me.

My code :

```
//Deactive
GameObject.Find ("light0").SetActive (false);
//Active
GameObject.Find ("light0").SetActive (true);
```

Comment: Hi, can you please provide more information (and code)? To answer your question we need some context. Please have a read how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Moseleyi  .......I Edit

Comment: Your edit does not shed much light. Where does this code appear in your application? Are you seeing an error? What exactly does "don't work for me" mean?

Comment: @DanPuzey..... I receive  not set to be Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @Moseleyi  please help

Comment: @DanPuzey please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to `Find` the gameobject if it is deactivated. You could store a reference to the object and deactivate/activate it afterwards instead.

```
    GameObject[] lights = new GameObject[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        lights[i] = GameObject.Find("light" + i.ToString());
        lights[i].SetActive(false);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
    {
        lights[j].SetActive(true);
    }
```

Comment: for (i = 0; i <26; i++) {


   GameObject light = GameObject.Find ("light" + i.ToString ());
   light.SetActive (false);
  }
  GameObject light1 = GameObject.Find("light0");

  light1.SetActive (true); don't work for me

Comment: You are still trying to find the object after you deactivate it. That will not work. If you are trying to deactivatee and then activate an entire set of lights in the way you have described, you can try storing all of your lights in an array first. When you want to Activate the lights you need to loop through the _same_ array. If possible, you are probably better off storing all of your lights under a parent gameobject and simply toggling that parent instead.

Comment: Well, is there a way? To call the disabled object except find

Comment: You either need to store a reference to the gameobject or locate its Transform Otherwise you need to get the parent and iterate through its children. I've edited my answer above to show how to store a reference to each of your lights in an array.